# Deriving flux equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

If we have

$$u_t + au_x = b$$ with initial condition $u(x, 0) = g(x)$ Let $x$ be a function $t$. Then   $$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{∂u}{∂t}+\frac{∂u}{∂x}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

This is the step that I cannot follow. I can set $x=f(t)$  which gives

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dt}$$ but can't progess from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your partial differential equaiton is given as:

$$1\cdot u_t + a \cdot u_x = b$$

Your system of characteristic equations is given by:

$$\dfrac {dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{a}=\dfrac{du}{b}$$

Using the first equation you will obtain $at-x = c_1$. Using the second equation will give you $bx+ac_2=au \implies u = \frac{b}{a}x+c_2=\frac{b}{a}x+c_2(c_1)=\frac{b}{a}x+c_2(at-x)$

$$\implies u=\frac abx+F(at-x).$$

In the middle, I used that $c_2$ is a function of $c_1=at-x$, this function is then represented by $F$.

Your final goal is to determine the function $F$ such that $u$ is fulfilling $u(x,0)=g(x)$.

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. Then   $$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{∂u}{∂t}+\frac{∂u}{∂x}\frac{dx}{dt}$$ That is the part I did not follow. And shouldn't $bx+ac_2=au$ be $bx+c_2=au$?

Comment: Use $c_2=a\tilde{c}_2$ and you will have my equation. I choose $ac_2$ as constant of integration such that I can divide by $a$ and only obtain $c_2$.